# "Unrecoverable build error" on any MSI Setup project

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-installer, compiler-errors, vs-error

Some time ago I got this error when building ANY Visual Studio Deployment project.

**"Unrecoverable build error"**

*I thought my VS installation was corrupted or I deleted some important files, but ...*

Comment: Well it is 2022 and this problem still persists with no obvious solution.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

...all I had to do was.

**Close down** Visual Studio.

Start, **Run** or WIN+R, type **cmd**, OK.

```
regsvr32 "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\MSI Tools\mergemod.dll"
regsvr32 ole32.dll
```

**For x64 bit machines**

```
regsvr32 "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\MSI Tools\mergemod.dll"
regsvr32 ole32.dll
```

Warning: you **MUST** run the command prompt in **Admin Mode**!

**Close** Command Prompt.

**Open up** Visual Studio and try **rebuilding** your deployment project! It worked for me!

Comment: pretty awesome answer dude! +1

Comment: I'm sure it must be obvious, but Microsoft's instructions don't include shutting down Visual Studio, which prevented them from working for me. Thank you!

Comment: This worked for me using Visual Studio 2005 running on Windows 7 64 bit.  I did not need the second command "regsvr32 ole32.dll".

Comment: Don't forget that if you're running on an x64-bit machine, you'll have to reference mergemod.dll from `C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\MSI Tools\mergemod.dll`

Comment: Also, don't forget to run cmd as administrator. Otherwise you might get an error with the infamous code 0x80004005.

Comment: Unluckily this didn't worked for me on Visual Studio 2013 Winforms Application Setup. Do you any idea what else can cause this?

Comment: This thing worked from me! Thanks. Could you please state the reason of this error?

Comment: Visual Studio 2017 64 bit worked only when using @Tr1stan edit.

Comment: Worked for VS2019

Comment: Also worked for VS2022 (October 2023)

Answer (score 6):

We had this problem, and the solutions above didn't work for us. After several days of head-scratching, we found that the solution for us was to delete all the VSI*.TMP files from the local user temp folder at:

C:\Documents and Settings\username\Local Settings\Temp

In our case this went wrong on a Hudson build machine - Visual Studio seems to create temp files and not clean them up properly. Once it has created 65536 temp files (VSI0000.tmp to VSIFFFF.tmp) it can't create any more and MSI projects will fail to build.

Kudos to this blog post for the solution:

http://blog.richardadleta.com/2009/08/using-visual-studio-command-line.html

Comment: I tried to delete these files but it is showing me message "Files are no longer available" even if I am able to see it in the search results

Comment: my temp files were located in : c:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\

Answer (score 5):

This can also occur if you are including Project Output as "Publish Items" and you have not specified the PublishProfilePath that will produce the output. Unfortunately when you select this output type, you are not prompted to select this critical piece of information.

To specify the path, click on the Project Output item in the right pane of the File System window,
[image: File System tab]

then display the Properties panel for it (Ctrl+W, P).

[image: Properties panel]

Click the field and you should be able to select the desired publish profile for your project (if you haven't created one you will need to by right clicking on the main project in Solution Explorer and then click Publish; I created a Folder profile). Do a clean build and in my case the issue was resolved.

Note that I had previously registered the above mentioned DLLs, so it's possible that was part of the issue as well.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue in Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate. Registration tricks:

```
regsvr32 "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\MSI Tools\mergemod.dll"
regsvr32 ole32.dll
```

helped!

Answer (score 1):

tried those solutions above and... finally removing and adding Visual Studio Installer Project extension solved the problem.
Leaving it here as an alternative solution.

Comment: Worked for Visual Studio 2022, I tryed the above solutions first but only after doing this one it worked.

Answer (score -2):

Reinstall (Repair) Visual Studio resolved the problem for me.