# error when i try to make package

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

i try to make package and i got this error:

```
Unrecoverable build error
```

i work on Visual-studio 2008 in C#

thank's in advance

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/339106/unrecoverable-build-error-on-any-msi-setup-project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean that you get that error while trying to build a setup package? If so, look t this article: [PRB: "Unrecoverable build error" error message when you build Setup and Deployment projects](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/329214)