# Compiling MSI (Windows Installer) from asp.net application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio

We have the following problem, which is proving non trivial to solve.

We are building an MSI installer from within our Asp.Net WebForms application.

Firstly we build an exe.config file with user specific vars and then a vdproj file which is passed to devenv to build the actual installer.

This process runs fine when using the debugger but fails when running under IIS.  So instinctively we thought this must be a permissions issue but even setting the application as my own account which is running visual studio it still fails. Could there be another permission that is being missed, even though the compiler is defiantly being called?

Inspecting the visual studio log provides very little information and having had a dig around using the rather non descriptive error has proved to be fruitless.

```
------ Starting pre-build validation for project 'xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxx.Installer' ------ 
------ Pre-build validation for project 'xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxx.Installer' completed ------
------ Build started: Project: xxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxx.Installer, Configuration: Release -----    -
Building file 'D:\xxxxxxx.xxxxxxx.Installer\CustomerInstallers\9999-    12349237\xxxxxxx.xxxxxxx.Installer.msi'...
ERROR: Unrecoverable build error
========== Build: 0 succeeded or up-to-date, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

So more information, the application has been working fine on the server up until a couple of weeks ago but there is nothing really suggesting what could have changed as the application was working for weeks after the last set of updates were installed.

The application is running under .NET 3.5 the application it is building is .NET 2.0 
The compiler/visual studio version 2008 (9.0.21022.8 RTM)

Just for reference I have tried the solutions suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339106/unrecoverable-build-error-on-any-msi-setup-project) and [here](http://blog.richardadleta.com/2009/08/using-visual-studio-command-line.html) but still no luck.

Comment: Have you verified that there is enough drive space to do the build?

Comment: There is plenty of disk space available, I cleaned up over 5 gig worth of old builds this morning.

Answer (score 1):

Are you running this in an integrated or classic mode application pool? I had a similar issue, albeit with different circumstances. Changing the pool fixed the problem.

I mention this because we chased the same dogs you have, as far as configuration and permissions go.

Comment: Have tried under both integrated and classic and it makes no difference, thanks for the suggestion.