# ERROR: Unrecoverable build error - 0x8007000B

Tags: visual-studio, setup-project, visual-studio-2022

I'm trying to create a setup for my program on Visual Studio 2022 but everytime I try to generate it, I get this error:
ERROR: Unrecoverable build error - 0x8007000B
I already tried what was suggested here
["Unrecoverable build error" on any MSI Setup project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339106/unrecoverable-build-error-on-any-msi-setup-project) and also here [Unrecoverable build error - whilst trying to build setup on VS2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42624572/unrecoverable-build-error-whilst-trying-to-build-setup-on-vs2015?noredirect=1&lq=1)
but it still doesn't work.

Any idea why ?

Also do you have any suggestions on alternatives ?

I tried with the wizard setup of Wix and I get the exact same error.